# Ckeditor5 How to Search text in editor for predefined words and when found manipulate the style of them in just the editor view?

Tags: ckeditor5, angular12

let say we have predefined array contain Arabic/English words and I want to search in the loaded data to editor or any new data inserted if the we found a word match then manipulate it's style on just the editor view without affect the inputted data or the output of the editor how can i achieve that ?

I try using conversion rule (downcast) but I need to downcast any text and I couldn't find a downcast for that in the documentation